# Integration services deployment straight to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2013, ssms

I have a custom Integration Services script which produces an `ispac` file for me. I want to deploy this `ispac` to SQL Server with SSMS, but I get an error, it's deployed but packages can't be executed and I get error like:

> Data Flow Task:Error: The component metadata for "some package, clsid
> {33D831DE-5DCF-48F0-B431-4D327B9E785D}" could not be upgraded to the
> newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.

and

> Data Flow Task:Error: The component is missing, not registered, not
> upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information
> for this component is "Includes and runs custom script code. For
> example, apply a business rule that limits the range of valid values
> in an "income" column or add values in two columns and calculate the
> average of the sum.;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server;
> Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved;
> [http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;11"](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;11%22).

This is not the case when deploying from Visual Studio which is located on another machine, lets call it the Development machine, everything works fine and as expected.

Server is equipped with Windows server 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2014. I'm deploying from Visual Studio 2013.

My questions:

- What happens differently when deploying from Visual Studio?
- What's wrong?

Comment: Without seeing any code, my assumption is that the ispac you are building is for SQL Server 2012 (aka the 11 in error message). When you're deploying, you're deploying a 2012 ispac file into a SQL Server 2014 SSISDB. The deploy is fine but the internals need upgrading before they can run - which is what the error says. When you deploy from Visual Studio, the `isdeploymentwizard` that is being invoked is likely the 2014 version of the the deployment tool. It is upgrading the ispac to 2014 format as part of the deployment

Comment: You can find this out though - Deploy from your custom tool. Export that ispac out of SQL Server. Deploy the same ispac through Visual Studio to SQL Server and then export back out. Compare your two ispac(s). Future readers, an ispac file is just a zip file. Change the extension to .zip and you can unzip the contents and compare.